# How to make three columns the same height?

Tags: css

I've viewed a dozen questions and answers to this issue, but there doesn't seem to be a single best answer for my situation.

I've got a page (http://awesomealbums.info/?1062/chris-cornell) with three vertical columns. I want the columns to appear to be the same height, whether there is adequate content in them or not.

The three columns are:

1) The navigation column on the left
2) The content column in the middle
3) The ad column on the right

What are the CSS/div options to make this happen?

Comment: I don't see the three columns :P

Comment: 1) The navigation column on the left 2) The content column in the middle 3) The ad column on the right

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-right-menu-pixels.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's old school, but http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Answer (score 3):

I recently found the PERFECT solution.  This does require the use of JavaScript / jQuery though.  Basically, once the page is loaded, get the natural height of all of the divs. Choose the greatest natural height of each the divs. Set all of the divs to the that height.

```
<style>

body {
    font-size: .9em;
}
#ProductWrapper {
    width: 620px;   
    float: left;
}
.ProductDiv {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    margin: 1px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```
<div id="ProductWrapper">
<div class="ProductDiv" data-nat-height=''>asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf</div>
<div class="ProductDiv" data-nat-height=''>asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf </div>
<div class="ProductDiv" data-nat-height=''>asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// GET MAX NAT HEIGHT
var MaxHeight = 200;
$(".ProductDiv").each(function() {
    var Height = $(this).height();
    if (Height > MaxHeight) {
        MaxHeight = Height;  
    }
    $(this).attr("data-nat-height", Height);
});
// SET TO MAX HEIGHT
$(".ProductDiv").css("height", MaxHeight+"px");

});
</script>
```

Comment: Making your MaxHeight variable initialise at 0 would be even better! Basically, that initial value would be the minimum height you want for your columns.

Comment: @Fredy31, I came to the same conclusion and edited my code in real life. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative margin'hack'.

Give each column a margin-bottom of -9999 and a padding-bottom of 9999, and a height of 100%. I'm not sure if that is the right way round or not though. But the idea is that as one container expands, the others will also all expand due to the 100% height, the padding and margin work such that the margin is hidden outside the 100% height - Google for 'negative margin columns'.

Alterantivly use css-discuss to see all the industry recognised ways to build 3 column layouts, there are fluid examples - http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Three_Column_Layouts

Comment: This seems to be a good solution to a tough problem. Many of the solutions seem odd to me, eg, tables, CSS tables, faux columns... Thanks for the conciseness of how you put it.

Answer (score 0):

One way (since your columns are fixed width anyway) is to use positioning (absolute to be exact).  With this method you might change your css rules to the following:

```
#PagePad {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}

#Column_1_3 {
    border-left: 1px #7D7D7D SOLID;
    width: 175px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}

#Column_2_3 {
    width: 540px;
    border-left: 1px #7D7D7D SOLID;
    border-right: 1px #7D7D7D SOLID;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 196px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#Column_3_3 {
    width: 180px;
    border-right: 1px #7D7D7D SOLID;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 778px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

not sure how cross-browser it is though.